# Should I use Google Cloud for my PHP web sites

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am looking for server space for my websites. One of them is built with PHP.

I am a student and can't afford much. My school's server space they give each of us for e-mail doesn't allow server-side programming.

Should I use Google Cloud?

I need to be able to SSH into the PHP web app, can I do that with Google Cloud?

I also need dynamic dns so I can tell my domains to go to the sites.

Or should I just buy server space somewhere.

Comment: Good Cloud Storage is primarily for storing data. For a virtual computer you can SSH into, you'd want the forthcoming Google Compute Engine or one of its competitors, like Amazon's EC2.

Comment: When is Google Compute Engine coming out?

Comment: Google Compute Engine is openly available now for customers who purchase a gold support agreement. See http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2013/04/google-compute-engine-expanded.html for more details.